# MySQL for loop to show grouped results

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to show results for 12 months using this query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as customers,
    SUM(amount)*.01 as amount,
    SUM(amount_refunded)*.01 as refunded,
    MONTH(MAX(created_at)) as month
FROM `payments`
WHERE `amount` > 0
AND `status` = 'succeeded'
AND `created_at` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH AND NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
AND `user_id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `created_at` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH AND NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
```

Could easily do this programmatically using PHP to output into an HTML table where each row includes shows a different month by incrementing the month and querying the DB again each time.

How would I do that with this query using a MySQL FOR loop instead? Would that even be the right approach?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY MONTH(created_at)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rick James mentioned, a `GROUP BY` function should do the trick here, and you can use  [This SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5027699/5517065) to limit it to the last 12 months.  For your example, the query would look something like this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as customers,
    SUM(amount)*.01 as amount,
    SUM(amount_refunded)*.01 as refunded,
    MONTH(MAX(created_at)) as month
FROM `payments`
WHERE `amount` > 0
AND `status` = 'succeeded'
AND `created_at` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
-- AND `user_id` IN (
--  SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `created_at` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
-- )
GROUP BY MONTH(`created_at`);
```

**NOTE:** I commented the subquery for `user_id` because it would mean the results were only for those customers who both created an account *and* made a purchase in the last year, and I wasn't sure if that was your desired result.  If so, just uncomment it.  I edited the subquery so that it should work in that manner

Comment: Not exactly the same, given how the OP is calculating the month period in their existing query. They appear to want to aggregate data between points 1 month from now and now, then 2 months from now and 1 month from now, then 3 months from and and 2 months from now etc. Simply grouping by `MONTH(created_at)` as in this solution will give you data by calendar months, which is different.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, @AndriyM.  You are certainly right.  I will take another look and see if I can edit the answer to fit.